# How to get "real" objects from jquery selector

Tags: jquery, oop

When I write OO-style javascript, I end up with objects, which are often derived from `<div>`s. I add my own attributes and member functions an use jquery's appendTo() method to place it into the DOM.

```
 tev.layout = function() {
                ...                    
        };

 tev.appendTo(lane.scrolled);
```

However, when I retrieve such objects by means of a jquery selector, my attributes are no longer present. In the above example the layout() function is no longer visible. I *can* add attributes using jquery's attr() function, but this seems ugly.

Occasionally I worked around this problem by keeping my own private copies of objects around. These objects will preserve all attributes I gave them. However, this seems like a waste, because I will have to write my own object-traversal queries instead of using jquery.

What is the best way to make jquery selectors return my objects will all their attributes?

Comment: $(selector).get(0) if I remember correctly.

Comment: If thats what you're looking for a shorter one would be `$(selector)[0]...`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have here is that you are appending custom properties to the jQuery object, but every time you call `$` you are generating a new jQuery object with the matched elements.

Consider this:

```
var a = $("div"), b = $("div");
a.testProperty = true;
alert(b.testProperty); // undefined
```

You aren't actually adding the property to the element. However, if you do this:

```
var a = $("div"), b = $("div");
a[0].testProperty = true;
alert(b[0].testProperty); // true
```

Since the property is being added to the underlying DOM node, which is the exact same node in both objects, the property is accessible on both sides.

Comment: I don't think he asking for this solution. In your solution you are keeping a copy of the dom elements. What he wants is that the ```b=$('div')``` when called after setting the ```testproperty``` should also have the value as true. Which technically is not possible.

Comment: Likely to cause memory leaks on IE<=8

Answer (score 1):

Use the data function.

```
var $element = $('some_selector')
$element.data("stuff", {
    layout: function(){}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you can not. I think you need to understand the difference between HTML and DOM. DOM is an API which can be used by the browser to manipulate the HTML which inturn turns out to be text. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306870/confused-by-relation-between-dom-and-html-apis) question for more details.

So basically when you use JQuery it makes changes through the DOM api only and thus are limited to what the api exposes. The solutions that you have already tried are the only alternatives and the most frequently used.